# How to only show specific elements in a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, database, cursor

I have a custom CursorAdapter that is taking items from a database and displaying them in a listview. If possible, I would like to display only certain elements based on some boolean value within a database element. Here is something similar to what I would like to do:

```
package itp.uts.program;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
//Adapter tests if an element is read or unread, and bolds the items that are unread
public class BoldAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
public BoldAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public BoldAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Creates a view to display the items in
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, parent, false);
    TextView textRequestNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView textMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    StringBuilder requestNo = new StringBuilder(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("requestNo")));
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("Message")));

    //Sets the text fields as elements from the database
    textRequestNo.setText(requestNo);
    textMessage.setText(message);

    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Read")).equals("true"))
    {//Tests if the item is unread
        **//DO NOT SHOW THE ELEMENT, HOW DO I DO THIS?**
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you just filter out the rows you don't want in your database query.

If, for whatever reason, that is not possible, create a wrapping adapter that filters out the rows you do not want. Here is an [`AdapterWrapper`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-adapter) base class you can use to help.

Comment: Didn't even think of this, thanks. What exactly would I query for though. I have never really dealt with database querying before, and only know that I would change some parameter in this call:  return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_BODY1, KEY_BODY2, KEY_BODY3, KEY_BODY4, KEY_BODY5}, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: @mbauer14: That's really impossible to answer, since I did not create your database schema. You really need to spend some time learning SQL before creating Android apps that use SQLite. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah I definitely do, I have just been trying to learn as I go, but with databases, it seems like this just doesn't work. Say I want to return as a cursor all elements where KEY_BODY3 is false, is this a simple operation or do I just need to read up more? Thanks

Comment: @mbauer14: There is no `false` in SQLite, since there is no boolean datatype. Try making your third parameter to `query()` to be `KEY_BODY3+"=0"`, if that column is an integer and `0` represents false. But I really really recommend that you spend some time learning SQL before creating Android apps that use SQLite. Sorry!

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to use the WHERE call for selection. I have been using Strings for the true and false fields, I should have mentioned that, but I got what I needed using : return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_BODY1, KEY_BODY2, KEY_BODY3, KEY_BODY4, KEY_BODY5}, "Read= 'false' ", null, null, null, null);

Comment: Could you provide an example of using `AdapterWrapper`? Something that will for example skip a row if a `skipRow(String rowId)` function returns true.

Comment: @cprcrack: Sorry, I don't have an example like that handy.

Answer (score 0):

just return a View and set it's visibility property to `VIEW.GONE`

Comment: This makes the actual element disappear, but leaves an empty space where the item would be in the list.